# Convert a .net 2.0 dll to .net 4.0 dll

Tags: .net

i want to convert a .net dll from version 2.0 to .net 4.0.The issue is that i have only the .dll no source code.Is there any way?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You can use a .NET decompiler to generate source code based on a DLL and recompile the resulting code using v4.0 compiler. There may be compile errors if you use a deprecated methods.

Decompilers:

- http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/
- http://www.reflector.net/
- etc.

Comment: i have downloaded jetbrains dotpeek.It is decompiling the source.
But how can i create the upgraded dll with that

Answer (score 0):

I use Reflector to reverse engineer the assembly and then rebuild it using Visual Studio. Please note, if you don't have the original .snk file used to sign the assembly the Public Key Token will be different. If you are using it inside BizTalk, for example, you will need to search all BizTalk artifacts for the old PKT and replace it with the new PKT. If the PKT doesn't matter you are good to go.